# How do backslashes and parentheses work in re.findall()?

Tags: python

Currently, have

```
for i in re.findall('href=\\"/sauce(.*?)\\"', s, re.DOTALL):
```

But there seems to be an error in how I'm writing the starting and ending keywords. My intention is for the starting keyword to = 
**href=\"/sauce** and the ending keywrod to = **\"**.

For more clarification

```
for i in re.findall('starting keyword(.*?)ending keyword', s, re.DOTALL):
```

Comment: Backslashes get a lot less complicated if you change from regular strings (`'...'`) to *raw* strings (`r'...'`), because that way they're literal (Python doesn't try to do anything special with them, as it does usually; to provide an example, `r'\n'` is two characters, whereas `'\n'` is just one).

Comment: ...that said, trying to use regular expressions for parsing HTML is exceedingly error-prone. Really, don't do it -- even the purportedly-simple code you're using here, for example, doesn't know how to ignore HTML comments, CDATA sections, spaces around the `=` in an attribute assignment, etc etc etc. (Also, HTML is case-insensitive, so you'd need to match `HREF=`; use a real HTML parser instead -- the Python ecosystem has got [some great ones](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)).

Comment: Beyond that -- instead of just saying that there "seems to be an error", provide the **exact** error itself (or expected and actual output given a specific input string) inside the question text.

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes in a regexp.